PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare distance() when making a new block
I created a ACF block.  It calculates the distance from the displayed ski resort to the 3 closest ski resorts and displays a summary and is meant to use in a side bar or something.
I have a function called distance() that takes two latitude and longitude points and calculates the difference.  I am getting a PHP Fatal Error when I edit the custom post type fs_ski_resorts, although in the front end everything displays correctly.  Also, I have added this block to 2 custom post types.  They both display perfectly, however, 1 of the 2 produces the fatal error in the backend with editing it.  There is only 1 block on the page, too.  Strange.
[25-Aug-2024 12:09:31 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare distance() (previously declared in /home/example/htdocs/www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/fs-nearby-resorts-block/template-parts/fs-nearby-resorts-block-template.php:101) in /home/example/htdocs/www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/fs-nearby-resorts-block/template-parts/fs-nearby-resorts-block-template.php on line 101

I have only declared distance one, however, it seems somehow it is getting declared twice.  I cannot figure out how to debug this anymore... any ideas on how to debug or what the problem may be?
Here is the code:
<?php    
$id = 'fs-nearby-resorts-block-'.$block['id'];
if(!empty($block['anchor'])){
    $id =  $block['anchor']; 
}

if(!empty($block['className'])){
    $className .= ' '.$block['className']; 
}

//if(!empty($block['align'])){
//    $className .= ' align'.$block['align']; 
//}

$className = "fs-nearby-resorts-block";

global $post;
$post_slug  = $post->post_name;

$distanceFromSkiResort  = 100; // in kilometers.

$latitude_from              = do_shortcode('[fs_ski_resort_field key="aa_y" id="'.$post_id.'"]');
$longitude_from             = do_shortcode('[fs_ski_resort_field key="aa_x" id="'.$post_id.'"]');

// args
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    =>-1,
    'post_type'         => 'fs_ski_resorts',
);

// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>

<ul>
    <?php 
        $resortArray = array(); 
        
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
        
            $to_ski_resort_id = get_the_ID();
            
            $latitude_to = do_shortcode('[fs_ski_resort_field key="aa_y" id="'.$to_ski_resort_id.'"]');
            $longitude_to = do_shortcode('[fs_ski_resort_field key="aa_x" id="'.$to_ski_resort_id.'"]');
            $distance = (float) round(distance($latitude_from, $longitude_from, $latitude_to, $longitude_to, 'K'),1);
            
            if ($distance <= $distanceFromSkiResort) {
                
                if ($post_id <> $to_ski_resort_id) { // remove the current resort from the list of ski resorts within X km.
                    
                    $resortData =  array (
                        'get_permalink'             => get_permalink(),
                        'get_the_title'             => get_the_title(),
                        'distanceToResort'          => $distance,
                        'aa_pistes_length_km'       => do_shortcode('[fs_ski_resort_field key="aa_pistes_length_km" id="'.$post_id.'"]'),
                        'aa_lifts_length_km'        => do_shortcode('[fs_ski_resort_field key="aa_lifts_length_km" id="'.$post_id.'"]'),
                        'aa_pistes_count'           => do_shortcode('[fs_ski_resort_field key="aa_pistes_count" id="'.$post_id.'"]'),
                        'aa_lifts_count'            => do_shortcode('[fs_ski_resort_field key="aa_lifts_count" id="'.$post_id.'"]'),
                        'aa_min'                    => do_shortcode('[fs_ski_resort_field key="aa_min" id="'.$post_id.'"]'),
                        'aa_max'                    => do_shortcode('[fs_ski_resort_field key="aa_max" id="'.$post_id.'"]'),
                        'aa_ttl_vertical'           => do_shortcode('[fs_ski_resort_field key="aa_ttl_vertical" id="'.$post_id.'"]'),
                        'aa_novice_easy_length_km'  => do_shortcode('[fs_ski_resort_field key="aa_novice_easy_length_km" id="'.$post_id.'"]'),
                        'aa_novice_easy_count'      => do_shortcode('[fs_ski_resort_field key="aa_novice_easy_count" id="'.$post_id.'"]'),
                        'aa_intermediate_count'     => do_shortcode('[fs_ski_resort_field key="aa_intermediate_count" id="'.$post_id.'"]'),
                        'aa_intermediate_length_km' => do_shortcode('[fs_ski_resort_field key="aa_intermediate_length_km" id="'.$post_id.'"]'),
                        'aa_advanced_expert_freeridee_extreme_count'        => do_shortcode('[fs_ski_resort_field key="aa_advanced_expert_freeridee_extreme_count" id="'.$post_id.'"]'),
                        'aa_advanced_expert_freeridee_extreme_length_km'    => do_shortcode('[fs_ski_resort_field key="aa_advanced_expert_freeridee_extreme_length_km" id="'.$post_id.'"]'),
                    );
    
                    $resortArray[get_the_ID()] = $resortData;
                }
           } 
           
        endwhile; 
        
        array_multisort(array_column($resortArray, 'distanceToResort'), SORT_ASC, $resortArray);

        $i = 1;
        
        echo '<h2>3 Ski Resorts Nearby: </h2>';
        foreach ($resortArray as $resort) {
            echo '<a href="'.$resort['get_permalink'].'">'. $resort['get_the_title'] .'</a> is '. $resort['distanceToResort']  . "km away!</br>";
            echo '<ul>';
            echo '<li style="color:#339933"> Beginner: '.$resort['aa_novice_easy_count'].' runs over '.$resort['aa_novice_easy_length_km'].' km </li></br>';
            echo '<li style="color:#ed151f"> Intermediate: '.$resort['aa_intermediate_count'].' runs over '.$resort['aa_intermediate_length_km'].' km </li></br>';
            echo '<li>Expert: '.$resort['aa_advanced_expert_freeridee_extreme_count'].' runs over '.$resort['aa_advanced_expert_freeridee_extreme_length_km'].' km </li></br>';
            echo '</ul>';
            echo '<hr></br>';
            if ($i++ == 3) break;
        }
    ?>
</ul>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();   // Restore global post data stomped by the_post()

function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);
    if ($unit == "K") {
        return ($miles * 1.609344);
    } else if ($unit == "N") {
        return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
    }
}


It looks like you're defining distance() in a template file. Try moving that code to a separate file that is then loaded by the template file (using, eg, require or something similar).

To elaborate on @PatJ's point, a template file may be included multiple times. Thus, if there is a function declaration in one, that would be included multiple times too. Thus, this causes the redeclaration error.

Thank you very much.  I created a function.php and called it from my template with require_once('functions.php'); and it now works. If @Pat J sets the answer, I can check it as correct.  Much appreciated!  Also thank you to Wongjn !

It looks like you're defining distance() in a template file. As @wongjin pointed out in the comments, a template file may be included multiple times, and so on the second inclusion PHP will try to redefine distance(), resulting in a fatal error.
Try moving the function distance(){ ... } code to a separate file that is then loaded by the template file (using, eg, require or something similar).
